# How to update data between components in Angular 5 in real time?

Tags: angular

I'm beginner with Angular and I try to make some exercise. I have 2 components, one for getting text and one for display this text. I have got service and everything works fine when I'm using button to trigger function to change text. What I want to make, is to change text without clicking button or anything else. I already know that I can't use ngOnChange, beacuse it does not work.

component 1 ts

```
mytext: string;

constructor(private data: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMytext.subscribe(mytext => this.mytext = mytext);
}

changeMytext(): void {
    this.data.changeMytext(this.mytext);
}
```

component 1 html

```
<form>
<button (click)="changeMytext()">Start</button>
<input [(ngModel)]="mytext" type="text" name="mytext">
</form>
```

component 2 ts

```
mytext: string;

constructor(private data: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMytext.subscribe(mytext => this.mytext = mytext);
}
```

component 2 html

```
<p>{{mytext}}</p>
```

service

```
private mytextSource = new Subject<string>();

currentMytext = this.mytextSource.asObservable();

constructor() { }

changeMytext(mytext: string)
{
    this.mytextSource.next(mytext);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You don't really need a Subject for this. You can use simple binding. I have a discussion and example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

Comment: @DeborahK that's fair, however since he mentions it's an exercice, he might voluntarily be trying to make use of `Subjects` / `Observables` to understand how they work.

Comment: OK then ... I have a complete Subject/BehaviorSubject example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Communication

Comment: You'd still have to use a getter/setter. I'll provide a second answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getters/setters instead of a Subject like this:

**Component 1**

```
get mytext(): string {
   return this.data.currentMyText;
};

set myText(value: string) {
   this.data.currentMyText = value;
}

constructor(private data: MyService) {}
```

**Template 1**

```
<form>
<input [(ngModel)]="mytext" type="text" name="mytext">
</form>
```

**Component 2**

```
// This component only needs a getter
// since it is only displaying the value
get mytext(): string {
   return this.data.currentMyText;
};

constructor(private data: MyService) {}
```

**Template 2**

```
<p>{{mytext}}</p>
```

**Service**

```
currentMytext: string;

constructor() { }
```

NOTE: I did not syntax check this code. It was all written here, not in an editor.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is already so much code in my "you don't need a subject here" answer, I'll provide the Subject technique in this second answer.

You can use getters/setters with a Subject like this:

**Component 1**

```
private _myText: string;
get mytext(): string {
   return this._myText;
};

set myText(value: string) {
   this._myText = value;  // This line is not really needed because it will
                          // get updated by the subscribe below.
   this.data.changeMytext(value);
}

constructor(private data: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMytext.subscribe(
       mytext => this._mytext = mytext);
}
```

**Template 1**

```
<form>
<input [(ngModel)]="mytext" type="text" name="mytext">
</form>
```

**Component 2**

```
mytext: string;

constructor(private data: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMytext.subscribe(
        mytext => this.mytext = mytext
    );
}
```

**Template 2**

```
<p>{{mytext}}</p>
```

**Service**

```
private mytextSource = new Subject<string>();

currentMytext = this.mytextSource.asObservable();

constructor() { }

changeMytext(mytext: string)
{
    this.mytextSource.next(mytext);
}
```

NOTE: I did not syntax check this code. It was all written here, not in an editor.